# Django: Radio button onclick refresh the same page with the clicked value information from database

Tags: django, radio-button

I have  a Html page that has links and another html included in it in another frame.

```
base.html
{% include left.html %}
{% include right.html %}
```

I have radio buttons on my left.html. On-click on radio buttons, the right.html should refresh and display value from database related to the selected radio button.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I tried to call a python function on selection Which gets the record of the clicked variable and included that variable in right.html.Did not work.I assume it must page refresh issue with selected variable passed.How to fix it